# <meta name="msapplication-config" content="none"> for browserconfig.xml not working

Tags: windows-8, meta-tags, internet-explorer-11

We are developing a site for a client. We were getting a number of 404 requests for /browserconfig.xml. Then I read over here : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn320426(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn320426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that if you do not want to support a browserconfig request you could add **meta name="msapplication-config" content="none"** in the head section.

However, even after adding the above meta tag still I am getting 404's for /browserconfig.xml.
Any pointers on this?

Comment: Can you share a sample URL demonstrating this? Is this META in *all* of your pages?

Comment: This is how the meta tag is used. It is on all the pages.      


<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#000000">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/assets/images/Favicon_144x144.png">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="none">
</head>

Answer (score 5):

Adding a meta tag might or might not work. We also added this tag, but we still received 404 errors for browserconfig.xml requests all the time. At the end we decided to do a simple browserconfig.xml  and after that we had no problems.

Our browserconfig.xml looks like this and basically it just tells where 4 images are located.

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <browserconfig>
               <msapplication>
                 <tile>
                    <square70x70logo src="/mstile-70x70.png"/>
                    <square150x150logo src="/mstile-150x150.png"/>
                    <wide310x150logo src="/mstile-310x150.png"/>
                    <square310x310logo src="/mstile-310x310.png"/>
                    <TileColor>#8bc53f</TileColor>
                    <TileImage src="/mstile-150x150.png" />
                 </tile>
               </msapplication>
            </browserconfig>
```